# Adding Selenium Webdrive Test Cases to Jenkins

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins

I have been into QA for more than five years now, however my experience is mainly focused on manual execution. Therefore I decided to move into automation subject (C#, VS2015 and Webdriver) :)

Right now I would like to know how can I add Selenium WD TC into Jenkins for future builds? How can i run them and is there a way to monitor their results/progress/report?

P.s. For any support/anwsers/guidesm thank you!

Comment: Not following you 100% here but you can run Selenium Automation from Jenkins. I am using SpecFlow/SpecRun and it is all run from a command line call in Jenkins. I am not sure what test runner you are using but just search for it and Jenkins and you should find a ton of info. Each runner typically has a built in report and there are some plugins for nunit, mstest etc. you can also add.

Comment: Thank you for the information Dazed, would you recommend any good tutorials or guides for that ?

Comment: There is kind of a lot and not knowing what you are doing 100% makes it difficult. Google is your friend. You said VS2015 but what are you using for source control? TFS? GIT? Just google your your source control, testrunner,  jenkin's and you should get some decent reading.

Comment: Yeah, true my bad. forgot to add that I use GIT as source control :). I will what you suggested Friend. Thank you very much!